# Unable to create a PFUser; Error: Uncaught Error: change must be passed a Parse.Object (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.19)

Tags: objective-c, parsing, parse-platform

I am trying to create a PFUser using the following code

```
PFUser * newUser = [PFUser user];
newUser.username = @"hygdtrbrhrjlr123";
newUser.email = @"nkjdnfkd@gmail.com";
newUser.password = @"oipodsifpo";

[newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"ITS SUCCESSFUL");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"There was an error in registration");
    }
}];
```

The error i get in the Log is Error: **Uncaught Error: change must be passed a Parse.Object (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.19)**

I have put the same code in another Parse Application its working but only to this specific app its not working.

I want to know what does this error mean? Why is this happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. The problem was with Parse Cloud Code. I deleted the extra file i created in the Cloud Code and left only the main.js file and deployed it in Parse Cloud Code. I committed all the changes and it works now. Parse should give out more verbose errors.